# Parse JSON key starting in % with jq

Tags: json, jq

Assume the following output from a REST API (stored as `test.json` here):

```json
{
  "system": {
    "power": 10.5,
    "%mem": 0.5,
    "%cpu": 12.4
  }
}
```

I can easily query the first item:

```
$ jq '.system.power' test.json

10.5
```

However:

```
$ jq '.system.%cpu' test.json

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.system.%cpu        
jq: 1 compile error
```

According to JSON.org, a string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. **Any valid string can be used as a JSON key.** So `%cpu` seems indeed valid and, indeed, `jq` can handle this elsewhere just fine:

```
$ jq '.system | has("%cpu")' test.json 
true
```

Question: How can I extract the lower two properties from the `system` object?

Comment: just use quoted `jq '.system."%cpu"' test.json` as you've mentioned from the reference

Comment: Note how you write "jq can handle this elsewhere just fine", then continue to use the quoted form `has("%cpu")` – and not unquoted as `has(%cpu)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON keys are always strings, but jq *sometimes* allows to use them without string (if they would be a valid "identifier"). You must quote it if it contains special characters such as `%`:

- `jq '.system."%cpu"' test.json`
- or `jq '.system["%cpu"]' test.json`